# How to handle exception in JavaScript if any exception thrown while executing native java API

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, java-native-interface, phonegap-plugins

I am building a Hybrid application using Phonegap on Android, their is a scenario where I am calling java API from JavaScript using Android WebView.

I want to catch exception in JavaScript if any exception occur while executing Java Native API. When I execute this it works but when Java Native code throws Exception application crashes and gives below exception in logs

```
05-06 21:28:03.230: W/dalvikvm(705): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised

05-06 21:28:03.239: E/dalvikvm(705): VM aborting
```

Java Native Code:

```
public Object callNative() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("Exception Occured");
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
try {
   window.callNative();
} catch(e) {
    // Exception Caught
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you are calling your intended method from JavaScript:

```
window.callNative("STRING PARAMETER VALUE");
```

According to your example, you are calling a different, likely undeclared method:

```
window.callNative();
```

Change your code to call the method I supply in the first code block.

Comment: Sorry Josh that's my mistake but the issue is something else, how to handle exception in JavaScript if its thrown from native Java